# Calculate scattered rows's average in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The table looks like below:

```
testid stepid serverid duration
1      1      1        10
1      2      1        11
2      1      2        12
2      2      2        13
3      1      1        14
3      2      1        15
4      1      2        16
4      2      2        17
```

4 tests ran on two servers. Each test has 2 steps. I would like to calculate average duration of each step of all tests on the 2 servers given test id. For example, if given test ids are 1 and 2, the final table looks like below:

```
stepid avg_duration
1      (10 + 12) / 2
2      (11 + 13) / 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a `group by`, right?

```
select stepid, avg(duration)
from t
where testid in (1, 2)
group by stepid;
```

Note:  You might want `avg(duration*1.0)` if you want "normal" division.

Comment: @user1888955 You should consider accepting the answer if it helped.